# include social media in view page

Tags: 7, views

I'm using the[**Social media**](https://www.drupal.org/project/socialmedia) module to share in linkedin, facebook. I have installed the [**Widgets**](https://www.drupal.org/project/widgets) module. I want to include this to created field 'Linkedin_share'(image type).

Shall I need to add separate field for share? How to include this social media in view page.

Answer (score 0):

There is [sharethis](https://www.drupal.org/project/sharethis) contrib module. You can use this module to share contents in lots of social media.

Also, this module can be used as block, content field and links area.

So, you can put a sharethis block in a view.

Here's what you need to do.

1. Install & enable module.
2. Under Configuration > web services, configure sharethis settings. (For the view, you should check block under content at the bottom)
3. In block settings, place sharethis block on content region.
4. Configure the sharethis block to only show it on the view.

Comment: how to include sharethis block in view

Comment: I added few lines of how-to